# rMarkdown PDF doesn't read CSS

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm knitting an rMarkdown file into PDF.

I've added css styling at the top of the RMD file, but the generated PDF doesn't change accordingly.

Does the knitr PDF reads CSS settings?

```
---
documentclass: article
geometry: margin=0.5cm
output:
  pdf_document: default
---
<style type="text/css">

h1.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial-Black;
}

body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Are you using `pandoc` to convert the markup into a pdf? AFAIK, pandoc would not convert markup syntax into pdf. Probably better if you stick with LaTeX syntax for control.

Comment: Yes I'm using `pandoc`. LaTeX syntax meaning using `\fontsize{16px}\selectfont` correct?

Answer (score 5):

If you're knitting into PDF then you'll need LaTeX and pandoc skills rather than HTML and CSS skills.

[This introduction](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#overview) to the subject of using Rmarkdown for PDFs helped me, along with [this detailed reference guide](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf). Depending upon the complexity of your styling needs, you might also want to peruse the answers from the [TeX community](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) on StackExchange.

I hope this helps you.